# How to add border inside UIButton in iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using following code for adding border for UIButton,it works fine,But the border appears outside UIButton area.How to add border inside UIbutton area.Please help me..

```
[[button1 layer] setBorderWidth:7.0];

[[button1 layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: can you put reference image .what you want exactly ?

Comment: You can go subclassing UIButton.
there you can add another subview on top of button.
then set frame of subview little smaller than button frame and set its border.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of adding an inner border for a `UIView`. However, you can add a subview to it. Something like this: (Implement the below method in your .m file).

```
-(void)setInnerBorderFor:(UIView *)aView withFloatVal:(CGFloat)aFloatVal
{
    UIView *borderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, aView.frame.size.width, aView.frame.size.height)];
    borderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    borderView.layer.borderWidth = aFloatVal;
    borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [aView addSubview:borderView];

}
```

And then, you can call :

```
[self setInnerBorderFor:button1 withFloatVal:7.0f];
```

Comment: Don't forget `self.clipsToBounds = YES;`!

Answer (score 0):

I always use your same method to draw borders. 
If you want to draw borders inside you could use a background image.

```
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button1_bckg.png"]
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```